# Why label encoding for categorical features should not be used for deep learning/neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, categorical-encoding

Many online posts([here](https://forums.fast.ai/t/to-label-encode-or-one-hot-encode/6057) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580771/neural-network-categorical-data-implementation)) say label encoding would make NN/DL models think there is an ordering among categories, so it should not be used for categorical encoding for NN/DL models. But wouldn't NN/DL models be capable of modeling any non-linear relationship like XGboost? If this is the case, why NN/DL can't figure out whether or not an ordering is actually present among categories when label encoding is used?

Comment: Could you share some context where it was said?

Comment: @Tim examples are added.

Comment: The links seem to answer your question, don't they? Nonetheless, this seems to be already answered on our site, so check the linked thread.

Comment: @Tim I disagreed with them and offer the reason(NN modeling non-linear relationship) for asking it again.

Comment: What exactly you disagree with and why does the linked thread not answer your question?